# using seshat in python

Tags: python, cmake, ocr

I installed the package seshat using the following line since, I don't know `cmake`.

```
pip install Seshat
```

But now, I can only run it using python. Could someone please give me the python code to read the text from an image. If not, please give me the *cmake code* to install seshat from the cloned file.

I want to use Seshat which is used to recognize handwritten maths symbols. The link to repository is https://github.com/falvaro/seshat

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run `pip install seshat` , you install this seshat : https://pypi.org/project/Seshat/ which is used for real time chat windows

To use Seshat which is on github :https://github.com/falvaro/seshat and is used to recognize handwritten maths symbols, you must follow the instructions given on https://github.com/falvaro/seshat#installation

For usage you must follow instructions given on https://github.com/falvaro/seshat#example-of-usage

The Seshat on pypi and Seshat on github are not the same ones.

In fact the Seshat you want to use cannot be installed using pip.

Comment: Thanks a lot bro. It helped

Comment: Lol chill... I accepted it.. But I need 4 more reps to upvote... I'm new to stack overflow xD

Comment: @S_rockz Thanks a lot